# my delete method of axios didn't work while post method work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, axios

I am making likes, dislikes function.
everything is working fine, except this delete method

at React :

```js
const goDownLike = async () => {
  const variables = {
    fromWhom: user.userData._id,
    toWhat: toWhat
  };

  await axios.delete('/api/heart/downLike', variables);
}
```

at Node.js :

```js
router.delete('/downLike', (req, res) => {
  Like.findOneAndDelete(req.body).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  });
});
```

when I clicked heart everytime, it seemed like it deleted somebody's likes including mine

so I changed like this:

```js
router.delete('/downLike', (req, res) => {
  const { fromWhom, toWhat } = req.body;
  Like.findOneAndDelete({ fromWhom: fromWhom, toWhat: toWhat }).exec(
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    }
  );
});
```

but this is actually do not delete any likes, even mine!

I changed from this

```js
Like.findOneAndDelete
```

to this

```js
Like.deleteOne
```

and this is not working, too. it delete nothing.

so I changed `delete method` to `post method`
and finally it worked. 
my likes was deleted and somebody's heart was not.

but I don't want to use `post method` instead of `delete method` 
I want to keep the rules of RESTful.

What should I do?
What did I missed?

thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works with POST and not DELETE is that the second parameter for `axios.post()` is the body, whereas the second parameter for `axios.delete()` is the axios config object. This is presumably because [there has been some disagreement and change over time as to whether DELETE requests can or should have a body, and what should happen if they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).

You can pass data in the config object, as seen [here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/delete).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I hit a strange bug: [Axios can't parse 204 status codes](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3374#issuecomment-1962083710) sent from the backend. Simply changing `204` status code to `200` in the backend fixed the issue.

I was getting:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/user/ide
```

Which clearly shows that the parsing issue is contaminated to the error message (the full path is /api/user/idea, the last a is cutoff in parsing).

This took 2 hours of my life. As the most popular javascript request library on the internet, I would expect more robustness from Axios.